# Java getting packed files from jar

Tags: java, image, jar, blur

I've packed my JAR with images and other files, but for the code below, I'm wondering how to access the packed images.

```
float[] matrix = {
        0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, 
        0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, 
        0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, 
    };

    BufferedImageOp op = new ConvolveOp( new Kernel(3, 3, matrix) );
    blurredImage = op.filter(sourceImage, destImage);
```

How would I use this if I'm wanting to access an image to blur, but its packed inside my JAR?

edit :

```
    try {
                BufferedImage spritesheet = ImageIO.read(Content.class.getResourceAsStream("/Sprites/Enemies/enemy.gif"));

                float[] matrix = { 0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, 
                                   0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, 
                                   0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, };

                BufferedImageOp op = new ConvolveOp( new Kernel(3, 3, matrix) );
                blurredImage = op.filter(spritesheet, spritesheet);
this.setBackground(blurredImage);
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: Just load the image as a resource from the JAR?

Comment: @TimB How so, would somthing like : example.png work?

Answer (score 0):

I know your pain. Loading images from a JAR is something that shouldn't be annoying, but is. For one of my recent projects, I ended up with

```
BufferedImage spritesheet = ImageIO.read(Content.class.getResourceAsStream("/Images/image_to_blur.gif"));
```

Where `Content` is the enclosing class. Using Eclipse, you can create a resources folder and put all of your assets inside it.

Another option:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/"+location);
```

Another option:

```
Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
URL url = getClass().getResource("asset.png");
Image img = tk.createImage(url);
tk.prepareImage(img, -1, -1, null);
```

**Edit:**

Alright, to do "to load the background image from my Jar, then blur it, then set it as my background," there are a couple steps you'd need to do.

1. Set up a `JFrame` with a `JPanel` with an `JLabel` to hold your image.
2. Load the image from your JAR
3. Blur the image        (This depends on the type of blur you want, but I will assume Gaussian)
4. Set the `JLabel` as that image.

   ```
   public class wowthisisaclass{

   JFrame frame;
   JPanel panel;
   JLabel label;

   float[] matrix = {
       0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, 
       0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, 
       0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, 
   };

   public wowthisisaclass(){ //Step 1
   JFrame window = new JFrame("Title");
   panel = new JPanel();
   panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));

   label = new JLabel((Icon) new ImageIcon(blur(getImage("/path.png"), matrix)));


   //initpanel
   panel.add(label);

   //init frame
   window.add(panel);
   window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   window.setResizable(false);
   window.pack();
   window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   window.setVisible(true);
   }

   public BufferedImage getImage(String path){ //Step 2
   try {
       return ImageIO.read(wowthisisaclass.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return null;
   }
       public BufferedImage blur(BufferedImage src, float[] matrix){ //Step 3

       ConvolveOp cop = new ConvolveOp( new Kernel( 3, 3, matrix), ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP, null);

       BufferedImage blurredImage = new BufferedImage(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
       cop.filter( src, blurredImage);
           return blurredImage;
   }
   }
   ```

If you need any explanations, just ask. :)

Comment: Ok great thanks, but now how would use that image. Ill edit my post so you know what I mean.

Comment: Is your question how to apply the filter to the image?

Comment: Well yes, if you could help me with that too :) im quite new to this java graphical editing

Comment: @Kyranstart basically I want to load the background image from my Jar, then blur it, then set it as my background.